# glutPassiveMotionFunc problems

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

Im kinda new to glut and opengl and I'm trying to make camera movement on mouse movement but when trying to get the mouse position on the screen I assumed the method you want to pass the x and y to should just be referenced in the glutPassiveMotionFunc() parameter. But I'm getting errors when trying to give the function the CameraMove method. I know I'm passing the method wrong but Im not sure how.

```
void helloGl::CameraMove(int x, int y)
{
oldMouseX = mouseX;
oldMouseY = mouseY;

// get mouse coordinates from Windows
mouseX = x;
mouseY = y;

// these lines limit the camera's range
if (mouseY < 60)
    mouseY = 60;
if (mouseY > 450)
    mouseY = 450;

if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) > 0)       // mouse moved to the right
    angle += 3.0f;`enter code here`
else if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) < 0)  // mouse moved to the left
    angle -= 3.0f;
}




void helloGl::mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
switch (button)
{
    // When left button is pressed and released.
case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:

    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);

    }
    else if (state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);
    }
    break;
    // When right button is pressed and released.
case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);
        //fltSpeed += 0.1;
    }
    else if (state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);
    }
    break;
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:

    glutPassiveMotionFunc(CameraMove);

    break;

default:
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `helloGl` is a class. Then the answer is, you can't. A function is not the same as a method. The thing is that `glutPassiveMotionFunc()` expects:

```
void(*func)(int x, int y)
```

But what you're trying to give it is:

```
void(helloGl::*CameraMove)(int x, int y)
```

In other words a [thiscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall). This doesn't work because a [thiscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall) *basically* has an additional hidden argument in contrast to a [cdecl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). In all it's simplicity you can imagine your `CameraMove()` as:

```
void CameraMove(helloGl *this, int x, int y)
```

As you can see, that isn't the same. So the solution is then to move `CameraMove()` out of your `helloGl` class or making the method static.